How do I waterproof the edge of shoulder-high shower tile?
The tiles on the walls of my shower end about five feet up.  Above that, the walls are painted.  (The painted surface is a skim coat over old plaster rather than modern moisture-resistant drywall.)  This horizontal boundary is clearly intentional since the top tiles are bullnose.  Because the tiles don't go very high, the paint above them gets wet every time I shower and that water runs down over the paint-to-tile boundary.
High-gloss paint seems to be completely effective for keeping the painted area dry, but the paint-to-tile boundary is currently waterproofed only by painting a little bit past the top of the tiles, so that that boundary is completely covered in paint.  This fails sometimes, necessitating minor repairs that are nonetheless quite annoying because every time I do them, I can't use my only shower until everything dries.
Is there a better method for waterproofing this boundary?  I thought about caulking it but I don't know that a paint-to-caulk interface would be any better than the current paint-to-tile.  I also want to retain the possibility of painting the walls a different color.
Edit: I found this discussion of a similar situation.  There doesn't seem to be a consensus there (at least not one I understand).  Someone mentions the possibility that the bathroom was originally built without a shower (and therefore never designed with the intent of keeping that boundary waterproof) but I know that that's not the case for me because I still have the original 1929 tub/shower lever.

Caulking the seam between the tile and wall can't hurt. Use a latex Paintable caulk..
Apply the caulk. Smooth it with a finger. Give a final wipe with a damp sponge.  Apply your paint.
The paint is the first line of defense and a good latex paint will seal out water. Modern paints are very good at this and can resist moisture intrusion very well.  ( note the pic) The arrow points to the paint bubbled with water in a ceiling of on of my rentals after Hurricane Milton.  It held almost a quart of water!
Painting over about 1/8 inch of the tile should provide a very good seal.
Of course to have the best protection, the shower should be torn out and rebuilt with the newer better materials.


Do I paint that 1/8" and then caulk over the paint, or vice versa?

" Apply the caulk. Smooth it with a finger. Give a final wipe with a damp sponge. Apply your paint."  There's your answer.

Ah, sorry, I just blanked on that.

Maybe it goes without saying, but: "Apply the caulk. Smooth it with a finger. Give a final wipe with a damp sponge. Let caulk dry/cure. Apply your paint."

Just note that some caulks can get very hard when they age, and separate from their substrates.
